# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined, when trying to load MathJax to a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mathjax

I'm building a system that generates equations and math exercises for the user. The client sends a GET request to fetch the exercise, and the server responds with the appropriate exercise. For that, I generated a new div with the id "questionLoad", and set its content to the given exercise.
I tried to render it with mathjax with `MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub,"loadQuestion"]);`
but then I got the following Error:

[image]

Here is the relevant function:

```js
function startGame() {
    console.log("starting the game");
    let spinner = `
        <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
  <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
</div>
`
    // adding a loading animation until the server responds
    $("#wrapper").html("<h3>Loading .... </h2>" + spinner); 
    
    let requestDict = { // telling the server to fetch a linear equation
        type: 'LinEq',
    };
    const requestJson = JSON.stringify(requestDict);
    fetch(`the server path`)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.text();
        }).then(function(server_response) { 
            // change the text of the div from a loading to the loaded equation
            $("#wrapper").html(`<div id='loadQuestion'><span style='font-size:25px;'>${server_response}
                   </span></div>`);
            // load MathJax into the div. Doesn't work!
            MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, "loadQuestion"]);
            
        });
}
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to supply the DOM element as the third argument, not the id of the DOM element.

### MathJax version 2

```js
MathJax.Hub.Queue([
    'Typeset', 
    MathJax.Hub, 
    $("#loadQuestion")[0]
])
```

Working sandbox sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-71615834-mj2-9w4b9f

### MathJax version 3

```js
MathJax.startup.promise.then(() => {
    MathJax.typesetClear([$("#holder")[0]]);
    MathJax.typeset([$("#holder")[0]]);
})
```

Working sandbox sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-71615834-mj3-yx1d41

In both versions, if you leave out the element to typeset, the whole page will be typeset anew.

Comment: Hi I was actually using mathjax 3 with asciimath syntax. I switched a syntax and to version 2 like you did and it finally worked!! thanks man

Comment: Aha, but I can provide an example with MathJax 3 too ... your syntax is MathJax 2 which doesn't work with MathJax 3 :)

Comment: ... and all of this works with AsciiMath as well :)

Comment: Yes, I just saw that the asciimath syntax in other parts of the code still works! you spared me many hours of headache

Comment: it doesn't let me give a bounty yet but I'll do it when I can

Comment: Cool, glad to help out! :)

Comment: While MathJax2 used id strings to identify the containers to typeset, MathJax 3 uses query selectors, so you would use `"#loadQuestion"` in version 3, not `"loadQuestion"`.  So the answer can be simplified to `MathJax.typeset(["#holder"]);`, and similarly for the `typesetClear()` call.  Just FYI.